# how to use python code out of the IDE

Tags: python, file, assembly, output, mips

i have implemented simple Mips instructions set assembler that supports set of 15 input instructions only such as (add, and, or, nor, ori, lw, sw, jr, jal, sub, slt, sll,andi, addi, beq),the program is to take the input single instruction from the user & output the machine code in output .txt file, i want to do some modifications, the first is to let the user enter multiple instructions until he wants to stop and how to print in a new line for the next instruction in the .txt file , how could i use the program out of the IDE i mean if i wanted to send the assembler to someone to use it directly what should i do, thanks in advance.
here is the code:

```
inst = raw_input("enter your instruction operation:")

if ((inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd') or (inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd') or (inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r') or (inst[0] == 'n' and inst[1] == 'o' and inst[2] == 'r') or (inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'u' and inst[2] == 'b') or (inst[0] == 'j' and inst[1] == 'r') or (inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 'l') or(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 't')):

        Rs = raw_input("enter the first operand:")
        for i in range (0,32):
         if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
            opcode = '000000'
            Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
            Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs))
            Mc_file.close()
        Rt = raw_input("enter the 2nd operand:")
        for i in range (0,32):
         if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
            opcode = '000000'
            Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
            Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt))
            Mc_file.close()
        Rd = raw_input("enter the destination operand:")
        for i in range (0,32):
         if(Rd == '$'+ str(i)):
            rd = "{0:05b}".format(i)
            opcode = '000000'
            shamt ='00000'
            Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
            Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt)
            Mc_file.close()

        if(inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd'):
              ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rd) + ',' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt)
              print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100000'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100100'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100101'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 'n' and inst[1] == 'o' and inst[2] == 'r'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100111'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'u' and inst[2] == 'b'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100010'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 'j' and inst[1] == 'r'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str('00000') + str('00000') +str(rd) + shamt + str('001000'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 'l'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('000000'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 't'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('101010'))
              Mc_file.close()
elif (inst[0] == 'l' and inst[1] == 'w'):
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '100011'
        Mc_file.write(str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'w':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '101011'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'j' and inst[1] == 'a' and inst[2] == 'l':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '000011'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'b' and inst[1] == 'e' and inst[2] == 'q':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '000100'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd'and inst[3] == 'i':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '001100'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r' and inst[2] == 'i':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '001101'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd'and inst[3] == 'i':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '001000'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
else:
    print "Not supported operation!"
```

Comment: When you say "use the program out of the IDE," do you mean that you're developing it inside of an IDE and testing it there as well and you're trying to figure out how to run it outside of the IDE--from the command line, for example?

Comment: No it's just an assignment if i wasnt supposed to send the code, i want to just send the file to someone to just use the assembler, or i have to send the code & the buddy compiles it & test it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Bartlomiej Lewandowski says, Python is an interpreted language and you need not compile it in order to run like you would with, say, C or C++. You could submit the script as a .py file and the person you are sending it to can run it from the command line by making the following call:

```
$ python script.py
```

assuming the file is called script.py. Note that $ represents the command prompt.

Alternatively, you could add the hash-bang to the top of the file `#! /usr/bin/env python` and run the script by calling

```
$ ./script.py
```

from the command line

Answer (score 0):

Python is a interpreted language. For a program to run, you need an interpreter. If you are on linux you can run the interpreter by typing python in the cmd.

If you want someone else to run this without an interpreter, there are tools : [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), that will make an executable from the python script.

If the other person has the python interpreter, you only need to send them the script.

Comment: does py2exe let me to deal with the output program only?

Comment: It creates an executable, that represents your script. So the answer is yes.

Comment: thanks, what about making the program taking multiple inputs from the user & assemble each instruction in a single line in the output file ?